# weak definite or regular definite: At home, we cleaned the windows

Tags: definite-article, semantics

[1] At home, we cleaned the windows.

What is your reading of this sentence? Regular definite reading; i.e., they cleaned all the windows of their house? Or, weak definite reading; i.e., they cleaned only some of the windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense of totality or partiality is *not given* in the expression "We cleaned the windows."  You can't confidently infer if they cleaned *all* the windows or only *some of* the windows.

The locative "At home" is rather odd, and distracting (It seems to set up a strange comparison to what you did "at work" or something...)  I'll ignore it.

The interpretation of such sentences is usually pragmatic. You need to apply your common knowledge of windows on homes.  It is quite possible that "the windows" refers to "The easy-to-ready downstairs windows" or "The big picture windows but not the little ones in the rear bathroom".

As such you can't tell for certain whether all the windows were cleaned.  However none were explicitly excluded.

Comment: So it's not the regular definite reading where the referent is all the windows, but weak reading. It ranges from two to some to all, depending how your common knowledge works. Thanks, James. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> At home, we cleaned each window

> At home, we cleaned every window

> At home, we cleaned all the windows

All those sentences mean the same thing as

> At home, we cleaned the windows

The fourth, however, might be used carelessly, particularly in speech, if all except a small number were cleaned. The point is that entirety is merely implied rather than **stressed** by the use of the definite article alone. The focus of the fourth sentence is the activity rather than number although number is implied.

> At home, we cleaned windows

Strictly, speaking that means the same as

> At home, we cleaned some windows

Again number is not stressed in “cleaned windows.” Thus, it may mean mean anything from “more than one window” to “all but one window.” The word “some” at least indicates that probably more than a few but probably not close to all windows were cleaned.

English has a host of terms to indicate the approximate degree to which a set is exhausted. If you want to be clear, use them rather than rely on subtleties in the use of the definite article.

no, not any, not one

one, a, an

a few, a handful

some

most of

almost all

each, every, all

English is lexically rich. Native speakers take advantage of that.

Comment: Well explained and easily understood. So it covers a spectrum of two to all but one. Some cognitive linguists argue the top end is all but that's not a point of question here. Thanks, Jeff.

Comment: a point of question >>> the point of the question